# Second Monitor has yellowish tint on white and darker colors overall

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, colors, displayport

I just bought a new AOC 24g2 for secondary display(DisplayPort). My main display is AOC 24g2e(HDMI). Both are plugged into a Gigabyte 1660 Super.

When I plugged in my second monitor, I noticed that white color is darker/has a yellowish tint on the secondary display monitor. I tried adjusting the settings on the OSD to be the exact same as the main display monitor but the yellow tint is still there. Also tried applying color profiles, did not work.

Anything else I can try to fix it or just send it back for a replacement?

Here is a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn2Xt.jpg) to an image I took. Hope this helps

Edit:
The old  monitor was bought 3-4 months ago.

Comment: This is common. New monitors "age" as you use them and their colour can change over time. If you care about colour matching then you should buy identical monitors at the same time, though you might be able to get most of the way there with software and hardware adjustments. https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-calibrate-your-monitor/

Comment: @Mokubai - just wanted to confirm. I should just use the new monitor and the yellowish tint would disappear in the next few days/month?

Comment: Just to add, the old monitor was bought 3-4 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

I came across your question a little late but wanted to share with you my experience.
I have 2 monitors, Dell P2419H. One on Display Port and the other one on HDMI and they did not had the same colors, similar to your explanation.

If you have set the same color profile in the **Color management**, now in the **NVIDIA Control Panel** try setting the "*Output dynamic range*" to full on the HDMI connected monitor.

[Nvidia Control panel dynamic range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5yFg.jpg)

Mine are now pretty much the same.